# calulcate size of data in each directory using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using the following code snippet to calculate the size of all the folders in each directory. I can pass the file path as a parameter in the form of widgets. I can achieve the requirement by giving the directory names one after the other however, the requirement is to achieve the size of the folders in a recursive manner:

For example, the following input paths are as below:

```
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export/
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export//BRedem/
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export/Sell/
/mnt/ADLS/Prepared/ModelExecution/gen/
/mnt/ADLS/Prepared/ModelExecution/hhp/
```

The expected output is:

```
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export/ 457783298 
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export//BRedem/ 846262827
/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export/Sell/ 88736291
/mnt/ADLS/Prepared/ModelExecution/gen/ 346727682
/mnt/ADLS/Prepared/ModelExecution/hhp/ 52781528
```

Below is the code I am using

```
def dirsize(path):
  total = 0
  dir_files = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
  for file in dir_files:
    if file.isDir():
      total += dirsize(file.path)
    else:
      total = file.size
 #     print(path)
  return (total)

path =dbutils.fs.ls ("/mnt/stoREC/datamart/export")

path2=[]
for i in path:
  path1=i[0]
#  print(path1)
  x=path1.replace('dbfs:','')
  path2= path1[i]
  path1[i]=path2[i]
  path2[i]=path2[]
  print(x)
```

I believe I am getting the logic incorrect somewhere since I am trying to use the swapping logic.

Comment: Hey @hari_agg, are you facing any specific error?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I have just updated the question and for the part of your question I am not getting errors but the results not populating as expected

Comment: Can you please clarify these? 1. The code you have given does not utilize the function `dirsize()` 2. When using `for i in path:`, i will be FileInfo object which can't be used as index for path2 (list) 3. why are we using path1 with index when it is not a list?

Comment: yeah thats the logic i am trying for in different ways where I should call the dirsize() to be used to take the necessary folder size calculation. Secondly since we have to iterate through all the directory location hence the loop is what i have used in the for i in path:

Comment: Can you also clarify why are you using swapping logic?

Comment: for the new directory location since there are a lot of directory locations and we are supposed to calculate for them all

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code and used it to find the size of folders that each path contains. The following is a demonstration of of the same.

- The following are the list of input files for which I need to calculate size.

```
print(mypaths)

#output (my sample paths for demo)

['/mnt/repro', '/mnt/repro2', '/mnt/repro/a', 'mnt/repro2/b']
```

- I have made slight changes to the `dirsize()` function code that you have provided.

```
def dirsize(path):
    total=0
    dir_files = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    for file in dir_files:
        #print(file)
        if file.isDir():
            #print(total)
            total += dirsize(file.path)
        else:
            total += file.size
            #print(file.path+"/ "+str(total))
    return (total)
```

- Now when you can iterate through your input paths (*mypaths*) to get the total size of the files/folders that it holds.

```
for path in mypaths:
    print(path+" : "+ str(dirsize(path)))

#output

/mnt/repro : 3445
/mnt/repro2 : 254
/mnt/repro/a : 2292
mnt/repro2/b : 254
```

**Output Image:**

[image]